# Read Linux or Windows MEX file on Mac OS

Tags: linux, macos, matlab, mex

I have 3 mex files:

```
extrema.mexa64
extrema.mexglx
extrema.mexw64
```

And I need to run this extrema function in Matlab on Mac OS. Please, tell me how to do this? I have only these three files!

Comment: Why would you want to read Mex files? Read the source code... Also, the code *is not* inside mex, not in a readable way at least.

Comment: @Intendia This cannot be done. You will need the source code in order to generate a mex file specific to OS X

Comment: @Suever that is a very bad news for me

Comment: @Intendia You could install MATLAB in a linux virtual machine maybe?

Comment: @Intendia You *could* try renaming the `mexa64` to `mexmaci64`. That's about the only thing you could try though as far as I know

Comment: @Suever: That will not work. The only way is to get the original source and compile it on OS X, or contact the author of the code ([this guy?](https://github.com/filipjares/tdv/tree/a3a6e82e0ce07649cdde5fffd992111d56aa4c53/src/wbs/private)) and get them to do so.

Comment: @horchler Ha that's what I figured, but I'd never actually tried it!

Comment: @horchler wow you actually found him :D Ok, I'll contact him, thank you!

Comment: not possible. `s=mexext('all')` will tell you the extension of each platform (you only have the linux 32/64-bit and windows 64-bit ones). You need to the source code to recompile it on your OSX platform